# MySQL how to split columns into multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table structure that looks something like this:

```
ID     column_1      column_2      column_3
--------------------------------------------
123       0             1              0
```

I am trying to end up with something like this:

```
ID    column    value
---------------------
123   column_1    0
123   column_2    1
123   column_3    0
```

Does anybody know how to do this in MySQL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is `union all`:

```
select id, 'column_1' as column, column_1 as value
from t
union all
select id, 'column_2' as column, column_2 as value
from t
union all
select id, 'column_3' as column, column_3 as value
from t;
```